# (How) Does Gravitational Teleport fit into container/Kubernetes environment?

Tags: ssh, containers, cluster-computing, kubernetes, devops

I am trying to evaluate [Gravitational Teleport](https://gravitational.com/teleport/) to be for maintaining our own architecture as we will expand soon looking into building clusters. It seems a containerized cluster using Kubernetes is where the bleeding edge is happening and SSH'ing into instances seems more like something you would want to do if you want to manage a lot of VPS yourselves rather than having an immutable infrastructure.

So is Teleport a parallell technology to Container / Kubernetes / Immutable Infrastructure or is it orthogonal, as in, can be used in addition?

Comment: maybe useful for direct access and debugging kube nodes. How do teleport nodes discover theirselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teleport can be used to augment a Kubernetes cluster.  Kubernetes gives you access into your pods/container, but does not handle the OS level access and control.

Teleport enterprise has extra features for Kubernetes via TeleKube- http://gravitational.com/teleport/docs/2.0/enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

Teleport manages to:

1. Deploys a inside-cluster and namespace scoped service(with its pod).
2. Creates a secure tunnel between your host and the service deployed.
3. Configure your localhost networking so it resolves registered services names using K8s DNS through your tunnel.

With all of that done you can send any request as if your host were inside the cluster.

Below is a graph that explain the full picture:

[image]